# Using sql developer with openedge database

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, openedge, progress-db

Is it possible to connect `sql` developer to `openedge db`, if not is there some alternative GUI that we can use with `openedge`?

Comment: I take it you want a DBMS? If so, the below answer may help (though it appears a bit unclear to me). If you're looking for an IDE, there is a plugin for Eclipse you can use. What version of Progress are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no.

We make 3rd party databases and their jdbc drivers (jars) available for customers needing to migrate those databases to the Oracle platform.

If and when customers need help migrating openedge db to Oracle Database, we'll consider it.

For now it's limited to Sybase ASE, SQL Server, DB2 LUW, Teradata, MySQL, and some limited support for PostgreSQL and Redshift.